# How to change high contrast icons to normal?

Tags: gnome, icon-themes

After switching off high contrast mode app icons remained high contrast. Turning high contrast on and of and reboot did not helped. How to return normal icons?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Had the same Issue,
I solved it going into Gnome Tweaks and changing everything in Appearance > Themes to Adwaita.

If you don't have Gnome Tweaks, you can install it:

```
sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
```

Hope it helps.